# Gap between checked toolbar button in Mac QT unified toolbar and titlebar border need to be reduced to ZERO

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, toolbar

In mac, created a unified mac toolbar with the title bar.
Also set toolbutton style to textundericon. But Found a gap between toolbar button and titlebar border when the toolbar button is checked or pressed.

Hope someone have a trick to reduce the gap to zero.

Attached the screenshot of the window

Thanks

[image]

Even after resizing the toolbutton added to the toolbar, the space between the toolbar border and the tool button is not get reduced. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I've never developed specifically for the Mac using Qt, but I usually call `QWidget::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` and set the appropriate parameter to zero. In this case you may try calling `setContentsMargins(x,x,x,0)` for the QToolBar and see what that gets you, where x are values you pick. IIRC, I think 11 is the default margin spacing for a QWidget but it may be different (and from the screenshot, does look different) for `QToolBar`, you can experiment a little and see if you get the look that you're trying to achieve.

I've also used a similar approach to tweak the spacing in `QLayout` subclasses with success.

Comment: Did this approach help you? If so, please mark the question as answered. If not, perhaps we can try again :).

Comment: No, Same issue still present even when i tried with setContentsMargin for toolbar & toolbutton.

Comment: On Windows you can supply a negative value for the bottom margin on setContentsMargins(...) and it will remove the gap. Although this approach feels hackish at best to me. I did just test it, though, and it does in fact work under Windows. I'm assuming the behavior will be the same for the OS X unified toolbar, but I'm not sure. Try something like QToolBar::setContentsMargins(0,0,0,-4) and see where that gets you. Bear in mind the 0's can be anything. Note that this approach doesn't hold up if you move the toolbar to a different side of the window. May not matter with a unified toolbar though.

Comment: Thanks Eli, But there s something hidden which we r missing here to achieve this. we ll find it soon...